# FontAwesome 4.2.0 problem

Tags: fontawesome

**Introduction**

I'm using updated TeXlive 2014 and the `fontawesome` package version is 3.1.1.

The newest version of FontAwesome font is [4.2.0](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) and it contains icons for [Linux](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/linux/) and [StackExchange](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/stack-exchange/).

So I downloaded the bundle from [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.2.0.zip) and just replace the `FontAwesome.otf` in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome
```

After that I run `texhash`.

**The code**

I have a (huge) `tex` file with a lot of material and also the code

```
\def\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\def\faSE{{\FA\symbol{"F18D}}}
\def\faLinux{{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}}
```

It compiles with no error and the PDF output is OK, as we can see below.

[image]

**The problem**

I have no idea why the MWE below does not work. The same problem without `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\faLinux{{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}}
\def\faSE{{\FA\symbol{"F18D}}}
\def\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}

\begin{document}
Linux icon: \faLinux

StackExchange icon: \faSE


Skyp icon: \faSkype
\end{document}
```

`lualatex` on the code above produces (icons missing)

[image]

I found here in TeX.SE a lot of topics but that solutions didn't work for me. I'd deleted the system font installed version.

Comment: You should not have installed the font to `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome`. It should be in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome`.

Comment: Have you deleted `~/.texlive2014`?

Comment: @cfr, no, I didn't delete. I'll move the font file. After that what should I run? `texhash`? `updmap-sys`?

Comment: @cfr, I moved the font file and deleted the folder on my home. After only this I run only `lualatex` again and no success.

Comment: Try installing the `.ttf` version as a system font. That's what I've got (and it is 4.2.0) and your MWE compiles fine with both `lualatex` and `xelatex`.

Comment: @cfr, where is the font file on your system? Do you mean `otf` or `ttf`?

Comment: `/usr/share/fonts/TTF/fontawesome-webfont.ttf` seems to do the trick. In my case, it is installed as part of `ttf-font-awesome` with my distro's package manager.

Comment: On my windows system, it works fine with the open-type version of the font.

Comment: I'd installed using synaptic a package with fontawesome but no success. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I found *Missing character: There is no  (U+F17C) in font "FontAwesome"!* in the log file.

Comment: Have you tried to run `kpsewhere FontAwesome.otf`? This will tell you which font the TeX engine is going to load, and you might discover that some folder with another version of the font takes precedence over the one you installed.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a temporary fix would be to work locally with the latest FontAwesome version. Grab the latest version of the font at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/ and copy the file named "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" in a sub-folder named "fonts" (or any other name) of your LaTex document location. Then, instead of passing through the fontawesome package, you can load and use the font manually like this (based on the MWE you provided):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path = fonts/]{fontawesome-webfont}

\def\faLinux{{\FA\symbol{"F17C}}}
\def\faSE{{\FA\symbol{"F18D}}}
\def\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}
\def\github{{\FA\symbol{"F092}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Linux icon: \faLinux \\
StackExchange icon: \faSE \\
GitHub icon: \github \\
Skype icon: \faSkype

\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get for this MWE:

[image]

It doesn't solve your problem globally for your system though... LuaLatex is probably grabbing an older version of the font package along the way  that override the new one you've installed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show us the output of your document as a screenshot?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Of course. There you go.